# Программа не работает как нужно(Не понимаю , как считанное значение после проверки проверить)

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int range = 11;
    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * range);

    int count, i;
    int tries = 4;

    System.out.println("Твоя задача угадать  число от 0 до 10");
    System.out.print("Введите ваше число --> ");



    for (i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
        count = scanner.nextInt();
        attempt(randomNumber, count, i + 1, tries, scanner);

        if (i == 3) {
            System.out.println("Вы потратили все 4 попытки");
            System.out.println("Заданное число было " + randomNumber);
            break;
        }
    }
}

static int attempt(int randomNumber, int count, int remainingTries, int tries, Scanner scanner) {
    remainingTries = tries - remainingTries;


    int temp;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your number: ");
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            temp = scanner.nextInt();
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong data. Please try again");
            scanner.next();
        }
    }
    if (randomNumber == count) {
        System.out.println("Ты угадал это число!: " + randomNumber);
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (randomNumber < count) {
        System.out.println("Не верно! Мое число меньше твоего " + count);
        System.out.println("Осталось попыток: " + remainingTries);
    } else if (randomNumber > count) {
        System.out.println("Не верно! Мое число больше твоего " + count);
        System.out.println("Осталось попыток: " + remainingTries);
    }
    return temp;


}
```

}

Comment: Не понимаю , как считанное значение после проверки проверить

Comment: Явное описание проблемы должно быть прямо в вопросе

Comment: ещё раз привет, что ты хотел сделать??

Comment: я доделал цикл в методе в конце, чтобы когда вводится не int то вводить другое бесконечно пока не введу int

Comment: и случайно всё сломал

Comment: всё работало нормально , но теперь самое первое значение которое я ввожу выбивает сразу программу, а 2,3,4 которые я ввоже работает нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int range = 11;

    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * range);
    System.out.println("Введите число от 1 до 50:");
    Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int scannerNumber = newScanner.nextInt();

    if (scannerNumber > randomNumber || scannerNumber < randomNumber) {
        for (int schetchik = 7; schetchik > 0; --schetchik) {
            if (scannerNumber > randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("Ваше число больше загаданного Осталось попыток: " + schetchik );
                Scanner newscannerT = new Scanner(System.in);
                int scannerttwo = newscannerT.nextInt();
                scannerNumber = scannerttwo;
            }
            else if (scannerNumber < randomNumber) {
                System.out.println("Ваше число Меньше загаданного. Осталос попыток " + schetchik);
                Scanner newscnnaerThr = new Scanner(System.in);
                int newScannerThree = newscnnaerThr.nextInt();
                scannerNumber = newScannerThree;
            }
        }
        if (scannerNumber == randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("Победа!");
        }
    }
    if (scannerNumber > randomNumber || scannerNumber < randomNumber) {
        System.out.println("Поражение!");
    }
}


 int temp;
    while (true) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            temp = scanner.nextInt();
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong data. Please try again");
        }
```

Comment: Извините а можно обьяснить как без try catch поожалуйста, я просто постепенно всё изучаю, это пока изучал, хочу понять как сделать таким методом, только с циклами for while и методы

Comment: у меня там впринципе всё работало , я только не мог понять как сделать чтобы оно и первое число считывало тоже

Comment: чтобы правильно работало короче

Comment: я могу объяснить. 
try, catch это обработка исключений.
try - это попытка что-либо сделать. В нашем случае это запросить с пользователя целое число.
в catch записывается то, что будет происходить если try не сработает. В нашем случае будет писать, что пользователь ввёл не int.
Значит словосочетание try, catch можно перевести как: "попытка, иначе"

Comment: и нельзя забывать про то, что нужно сделать i--, так как попытка уже засчиталась, её нужно так скажем убрать)